# Are there any pitfalls to testing for file existence in a while conditional?

Tags: perl, file-exists

I recently came across an interesting line of code that waits until a particular file springs to life:

```
sleep 1 until -e $file;
```

While at face value the line does what one expects it to, I can't but help feel that something is not right here; it just seems more natural to write the following:

```
while (1) {

    sleep 1;
    last if -e $file;
}
```

Are the file test operators intended for use only with `if` and `unless`? And are there any performance penalties in deploying such operators within `while` conditionals?

Comment: Performance??? The only penalty here is pinging the file system, which is by order of magnitude larger penalty than any loop...

Comment: @Drakosha : How long would you expect a typical file ping to take? Isn't a one-second sleep sufficient to combat the lag?

Comment: yes, looks like enough time on any normal filesystem/storage. I just did not understand why are you checking loop performance, which is negligible here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between using a file test operator in a while-true (`while`) vs a while-false (`until`) loop, or by separating out the test with an `if`/`unless`, nor is there a difference with anything else in Perl.

The only magical case with the while loop is `... while <$handle>;` or `while (<$handle>) {...}` which sets `$_` to the next line while it is defined.  And it doesn't really make sense to use the while-false (`until`) loop with bare handles.

The `a until b` construct is simply `a while not b`.

To convert `sleep 1 until -e $file;` into a `while` loop, you would use the following:

```
sleep 1 while not -e $file;
```

This can then be expanded to the block form:

```
while (not -e $file) {sleep 1}
```

Or as an infinite `while` with internal escape:

```
while (1) {
   last if -e $file;
   sleep 1;
}
```

And all of these forms are equivalent.

Answering the rest of your question, most file systems should be fine with 1 second sleeps between checks, but you many way to pick a larger number if the process is not urgently waiting on the file.  Also if you are on a device with a slow file system (stored in flash memory or via slow network) you might want to experiment with larger values as well.

And as `ysth` nitpicks below, in general, statement forms return differently than block forms when they are the last element of a construct that returns: `do {...}`, `sub {...}`, `do FILE`, eval ...

Comment: @Eric : I was more interested in comparing using file tests inside `while` conditionals as opposed to `if` conditionals. The `until`/`while not` equivalence is not the issue here.

Comment: @Zaid => that is the same issue, the file test, like any other operation in boolean context has no magic behavior in a conditional inside a loop (`if`) vs a conditional loop (`while`)

Comment: @Zaid: from your "seems more natural", it sounds like it is using the until statement modifier at all that bothers you.

Comment: until is subtly different:  compare `print do { sleep 1 until -e $file }` to `print do { while (not -e $file) { sleep 1 } }`

Comment: @ysth : The use of `until` doesn't bother me at all. The use of `until` with a file test does. I have yet to come across an example where file tests are used in conjunction with loop conditionals.

Comment: @Zaid => the file test operators behave the *same* in a loop conditional and in a plain conditional

Comment: Err, it's not a difference between statement modifiers and block statements, it's a difference between while and until; the last expression used will have opposite boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

Your more natural way seems to sleep at start even if the file exists.

```
while(not -e $file) { sleep 1; }
```

seems better to me, which is exactly synonym of `sleep 1 until -e $file;` but more understandable in my opinion.

Comment: Not an exact synonym; one will return false, one true.